# Firebase Android open activity using List view sub item

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to open a specific activity using the list view onItemClick listener.

Currently, I have it opening a single activity, based on the unique id that is created when the data is saved.

My opening activity code.

```
listViewWorkouts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            WorkoutDB viewworkout = workoutList.get(i);
           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddDetailActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra(WORKOUT_ID, viewworkout.getWorkoutId());
           intent.putExtra(WORKOUT_NAME, viewworkout.getWorkoutName());
           intent.putExtra(WORKOUT_CATEGORY, viewworkout.getWorkoutCategory());
startActivity(intent);
   }
 });
```

[image: .]

I need it so that when i click "Other" or "Cardio" it opens their specific page with their id

Comment: Can you explain what is your problem? I mean, you don't say what is going wrong and what you want to do

Comment: i need it to read the sub item on the list view, so it can open an specified activity

Comment: why do you need to read the subItem? You could check by the rows position as it seems you are using an static listView

Comment: because when the user is adding an item, they can click what they want from a drop down list. The "Test" and "Test 2" can be anything.

Comment: these are all saved in firebase, and the list view displays what ever workouts is saved.

Comment: This code seems to perfectly fine. What is the (unexpected) result that you're getting?

Comment: Your code is correct. What are the expectations regarding your code?